# How to write the below Cypher queries on Node Relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a sample database as under

```
CREATE (Prod1:TestProdNeoForJ {productname:'Product1'})
CREATE (A:Person {name:'A S'})
CREATE (R:Person {name:'R B'})
CREATE (L:Person {name:'L R P'})
CREATE (P:Person {name:'P R'})
CREATE (G:Person {name:'G K'})
CREATE (RK:Person {name:'R K'})


CREATE  
    (A)-[:WORKS_IN {roles:['Technical Lead']}]->(Prod1),    
    (R)-[:WORKS_IN {roles:['Technical Lead']}]->(Prod1),    
    (L)-[:WORKS_IN {roles:['Senior Developer']}]->(Prod1),
    (P)-[:WORKS_IN {roles:['Junior Project Manager']}]->(Prod1),    
    (G)-[:WORKS_IN {roles:['Senior Project Manager']}]->(Prod1),
    (A)-[:REPORTS_TO {roles:['Technical Lead']}]->(G),
    (R)-[:REPORTS_TO {roles:['Technical Lead']}]->(G),
    (P)-[:REPORTS_TO {roles:['Junior Project Manager']}]->(G),
    (G)-[:REPORTS_TO {roles:['Senior Project Manager']}]->(RK),
    (RK)-[:DH]->(Prod1)
```

[image]

I am looking for the below cypher queries on the Relationships

**a) Peoples reporting to 'G'**

(the answer will be: A,R,P)

**b) Peoples reporting to 'G' whose roles are 'Technical Lead'**

(the answer will be: A,R)

**c) Peoples directly reporting to 'RK'**

(the answer will be: G)

**d) Peoples directly/indirectly reporting to 'RK'**

(the answer will be: G,P,R,A) since A, R, P reports to G and G directly reports to RK

What I have tried so far (for the first one):

```
var query = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
          .Match("(m:TestProdNeoForJ)")
          .OptionalMatch("(a:Person)-[r1:REPORTS_TO]->(b:Person)")
          .Return((a, b) => new
          {                  
              cast = Return.As<string>("collect(a.name)")
          })
          .Limit(100);
var data = query.Results.ToList();
```

The cypher is producing the result as (of course because I have to restrict till G).

```
[
  "A S",
  "R B",
  "P R",
  "G K"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

a)

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(:Person{name:'G K'}) RETURN p
```

b)

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:REPORTS_TO]->(:Person{name:'G K'})
WHERE 'Technical Lead' IN r.roles 
RETURN p
```

Since you've choosen to use an array property for roles you need to check if 'Technical Lead' is part of that array using `IN`. Depending on the use case it might make sense to model the roles as separate nodes.

c)

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(:Person{name:'R K'}) RETURN p
```

Basically the same as a) .

d)

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:REPORTS_TO*]->(:Person{name:'R K'}) RETURN p
```

This uses a variable path length expression `*`.